# Node.JS - @hapi/joi - any.when() - not able to add .validate() at the "then condition"

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I'm not able to set the joi-schema that it is working as expected...

This is what I try to do:

- 'role' is an array and can contain items as string. Any value is allowed.
- But when 'internal' is set to 'true', only certain values in 'role' are allowed.

This is the code, which is **not working** as expected.

```
let Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const schema = Joi.object({
   internal: Joi.boolean(),
   role: 
     Joi.array()
      .items(Joi.string().trim())
      .required()

      // the when condition is not replacing properly
      .when('internal', {
        is: true,
        then: Joi.array()
          .items(Joi.string().valid("Admin"))
          .required()
  }),
});

console.log(schema.validate({role: ["Any Role"]})) // OK
console.log(schema.validate({internal: false, role: ["Any role allowed"]})) // OK

console.log(schema.validate({internal: true, role: ["WRONG"]})) // FAIL, should have thrown error
```

... while the replacing array function by itself works fine:

```
const passingschema = Joi.object({
  role: Joi.array()
  .items(Joi.string().valid("Admin"))
  .required()
})

console.log(passingschema.validate({role: ["Admin"]})) // OK
console.log(passingschema.validate({role: ["WRONG"]})) // OK - throws error as expected
});
```

Please let me know, how to replace the role validation accordingly, once internal is set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2409#issuecomment-660147391), this is the solution:

```js
Joi.array().required()
   .when('internal', {
       is: true,
       then: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid("Admin")),
       otherwise: Joi.array().items(Joi.string())
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `is: valid(true).required()` in the documentation it says you need required() on the `is` in order to make this work.

Comment: I might not understand what you mean, but according to the [any.when() doc example](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anywhencondition-options)

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.boolean().required(),
    b: Joi.object()
        .keys({
            c: Joi.string(),
            d: Joi.number().required()
        })
        .required()
        .when('a', {
            is: true,
            then: Joi.object({ c: Joi.required() }   })
})
```
there is just `is: true,`